# 9-patch behaving differently while setting in Java vs Xml

Tags: java, android, nine-patch, android-9.0-pie

While setting 9-patch using java it gets slightly stretched vertically whereas setting via XML works perfect.

Setting in code :

```
  button.setBackgroundDrawable();
```

Vertical edges are getting streched >
[image: Vertical edges are streched]

Setting in XML :

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_normal"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/btn_mainmenu"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:text="Menu" />
```

This is expected > 
[image: This is expected]

NOTE: I know workarounds but need to know if any reason for this behavior.

Comment: Tried but behaviour is still the same

Comment: I tried getResources().getDrawables() also using StateListDrawable stil behaviour is same

Comment: It is stored in drawable and it is .9.png extension... you could note it is working when set through XML. Question is why it's getting vertically stretched when setting through code?

Comment: Sadly, yes vertically stretched

Comment: If you check two images I have posted in the question. I am expecting the result like the second image.

Comment: Check left and right edges they are stretched vertically

Comment: Did you try button.setBackgroundResource() method instead? Would be curious how that compares.

Comment: yes I did try to set using this method as well